# python posting to a REST API behind a login form

Tags: python-requests

I am working with a web application where I need to post to various REST APIs, however, before I can post to the REST APIs, I have to login using our corporate SSO server.

The SSO login page contains two forms the second of which is the actual signin form, and contains a number of hidden fields.

I can successfully login using mechanize, but how do I then post to the REST API endpoints?
I tried using a cookiejar to save the cookies from the login process and passing the cookiejar to requests to do the posting to the endpoints, however in addition to the cookies, apparently there are a number of anti-csrf headers plus the session header added once loggin is successful.

How can I transfer the mechanize session to requests so the headers and cookies stay intact?

I also tried using requests to grab all the hidden fields in the signin field so I can pass them along with the username/password so I can use a requests session to login and then continue with the REST API posts.  However, because there are two forms on the login page, I haven't figured out how to isolate the hidden fields from just the signin form and exclude those from the other form.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you tell me how the corporate server does authentication? Requests has ways to handle custom authentication [link](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#custom-authentication)

Comment: I send the initial request to the web application which redirects to the SSO / CAS server. I enter my username and password click signin and the post includes a bunch of hidden anti-csrf and session specific fields.  It is not using basic authentication because it is using an actual post request not a get request with the username and password in the url.

Comment: It seems like you have an in-depth knowledge of how you need to authenticate. Is it impossible for you to mimic those actions with requests?